# New version of @ngrx effect is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>

Tags: angular, ngrx

I update my `@ngrx/store` to the last version `8.5.2.`

I need to get LIST of data from my API.

And now I create `action`

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { IListAll } from "./../../list.model";

export const loadLists = createAction("[List] Load Lists");

export const loadListsSuccess = createAction(
  "[List] Load Lists Success",
  props<{ list: IListAll [] }>()
);

export const loadListsFailure = createAction(
  "[List] Load ListFailure",
  props<{ error: any }>()
);
```

End here is `reducer`

```
import { Action, createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { IListAll } from "../../list.model";
import * as Listfrom "../actions/list.actions";

export const list= "list";

export interface State {
  listAll: IListAll [] | null;
}

export const initialState: State = {
  listAll: []
};

const listReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(SiteActions.loadLists, state => ({ ...state }))
);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return listReducer(state, action);
}
```

But when I try to set everything in `effect`

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from "@ngrx/effects";
import * as listActions from "../actions/list.actions";
import { concatMap, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { ListService } from "./../../list.service";
import { IListAll } from "./../../list.model";
import { ListFeatureKey } from './../reducers/list.reducer';

@Injectable()
export class ListEffects {
  loadLists$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(listActions.loadLists), 
      concatMap(() =>
      this.listService.getLists().pipe(
          map((users: SponsorModel[]) => new actions.LoadSponsorsSuccess(users))
        )
      )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, listService: ListService) {}
}
```

here is my `service`

```
 getLists(): Observable<IListAll[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IListAll[]>(
      environment.BASE_URL + this.API_SITE + "all"
    );
  }
```

I get this error

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable | ((...args: any[]) => Observable)'.
>     Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>       Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Action'.ts(2322)

I know that **effect should always return an Action** in last `ngrx` but I don't know how to do this in thy case

Also, Commenting out `createEffect(() =>` this works, but this is not ok solution.

Before this update, I use the "OLD" @ngrx method for action/reducer and effect and everything works ok,
now I want to convert everything on the last version rules...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is within `map` function:

```
  map((users: SponsorModel[]) => new actions.LoadSponsorsSuccess(users))
```

Since version 8, NgRx is using ActionCreators instead of classes. Action creators return functions, not classes, so you don't need to new up instances of actions. Change it to:

```
  map((users: SponsorModel[]) => actions.LoadSponsorsSuccess(users))
```

I've written a blog post on [how NgRx Action Creators work](https://medium.com/@mihalcan/how-do-ngrx-action-creators-work-bd8b17e02584). It provides information on internal building blocks of action creators.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `from` operator around the method:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

from(
  this.listService.getLists().pipe(
    map((users: SponsorModel[]) => new actions.LoadSponsorsSuccess(users)))
  )
)
```